# Вывод кастомных таксономий

Tags: wordpress

Сделал кастомные таксономии с общими рубриками через CPT UI. Необходимо при переходе на рубрику в меню, отобразить страницу с постами принадлежащими этой рубрике (со всех таксономий). Сейчас при переходе в шаблоне category.php, через стандартный цикл, отображается только стандартные записи. Как реализовать вывод всех таксоносий в этом шаблоне?

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон `category.php` отвечает только за вывод постов из таксономии `category`.
За вывод постов из других таксономий отвечает шаблон `taxonomy.php`. Вы можете создать его в теме и заинклюдить в него `category.php`, если вывод записей из кастомных таксономий абсолютно идентичен рубрикам, в таком случае код в `taxonomy.php` будет состоять из одной строки:

```
include 'category.php';
```

Кроме того, вы можете использовать общий для рубрик и таксономий шаблон `archive.php`, что разумнее в случае, если для тегов, авторов и архивных страниц календаря используется тот же дизайн.

Будет полезно изучить [документацию по иерархии шаблонов в Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Удобно пользоваться инфографикой как справочником.

[image: иерархия шаблонов в Wordpress]